# Bootstrap modal-within-modal image carousel issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal that will house an image gallery. When the first modal is opened, there are thumbnails, and when a thumbnail image is clicked, a secondary modal will open on top of the first modal, which will have the larger images in a carousel (of course whichever thumbnail is clicked, that corresponding large image will open in the second modal's carousel position).

Right now, when I click either thumbnail, the second modal opens up, but it shows both of the thumbnails, instead of the larger image of the corresponding thumbnail. Very weird, I seem to have it right by looking at the code, but not sure why it's not working.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!-- kitchens modal -->
<div class="modal kitchens-modal fade" id="kitchens-modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- modal header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1>KITCHENS</h1>
                <h3>Your dream kitchen is so close...</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- end modal header -->

            <!-- modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="./assets/img/kitchens/kitchen.jpg" alt="Kitchen" title="Kitchen">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="./assets/img/kitchens/kitchen1.jpg" alt="Kitchen two" title="Kitchen two">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end modal body -->

            <!-- modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            <!--end  modal footer -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end kitchens modal -->

<!-- inner kitchen gallery modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="modalCarousel" class="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">

                    </div>

                    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#modaCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#modalCarousel" data-slide="next">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end inner kitchen gallery modal -->
```

And the CSS:

```
.thumbnail {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 6px;
}

.thumbnail {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}


.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none;
    margin-top: 10%;
    width: 5%;
}
```

And lastly, the JS:

```
$('.row .thumbnail').on('load', function() {

}).each(function(i) {
  if(this.complete) {
        var item = $('<div class="item"></div>');
        var itemDiv = $(this).parents('div');
        var title = $(this).parent('a').attr("title");

        item.attr("title", title);
        $(itemDiv.html()).appendTo(item);
        item.appendTo('.carousel-inner'); 
        if (i === 0) { // set first item active
            item.addClass('active');
        }
  }
});

/* activate the carousel */
$('#modalCarousel').carousel({interval: false});

/* change modal title when slide changes */
$('#modalCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    $('.modal-title').html($(this).find('.active').attr("title"));
});

/* when clicking a thumbnail */
$('.row .thumbnail').click(function(){
    var idx = $(this).parents('div').index();
    var id = parseInt(idx);
    $('#myModal').modal('show'); // show the modal
    $('#modalCarousel').carousel(id); // slide carousel to selected
});
```

I got this from a modal gallery I found online, and modified it a bit, but it just won't work! When I open the modal, and click on the thumbnail, the second modal just has all the thumbnails there, instead of the one image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```js
$('.kitchens-modal .thumbnail').each(function(i) {
  var item = $('<div class="item"></div>');
  var itemDiv = $(this).parents('div');
  var title = $(this).parent('a').attr("title");

  item.attr("title", title);
  $(itemDiv.html()).appendTo(item);
  item.appendTo('.carousel-inner'); 
  if (i === 0) { // set first item active
      item.addClass('active');
  }
});

/* activate the carousel */
$('#modalCarousel').carousel({interval: false});

/* change modal title when slide changes */
$('#modalCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    $('.modal-title').html($(this).find('.active').attr("title"));
});

/* when clicking a thumbnail */
$('.row .thumbnail').click(function(){
    var idx = $(this).parents('div').index();
    var id = parseInt(idx);
    $('#myModal').modal('show'); // show the modal
    $('#modalCarousel').carousel(id); // slide carousel to selected
});
```

```css
.thumbnail {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 6px;
}

.thumbnail {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}


.carousel-control.left {
    background-image: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 25px;
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    width: 25px;
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.item .thumbnail {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
  margin: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#kitchens-modal" data-toggle="modal">Open Kitchen Modal</div>

<!-- kitchens modal -->
<div class="modal kitchens-modal fade" id="kitchens-modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- modal header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1>KITCHENS</h1>
                <h3>Your dream kitchen is so close...</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- end modal header -->

            <!-- modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="Kitchen" title="Kitchen">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="Kitchen two" title="Kitchen two">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end modal body -->

            <!-- modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            <!--end  modal footer -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end kitchens modal -->

<!-- inner kitchen gallery modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="modalCarousel" class="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">

                    </div>

                    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#modalCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#modalCarousel" data-slide="next">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end inner kitchen gallery modal -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!! Got it working. I saw the error after I went through your code, and I was right, it was something small I overlooked. Thanks a ton for your help!!

Comment: @Lushmoney Its my pleasure!